# Internal Server Errors with CUPS

Tags: printing, cups

Recently, I get internal server errors with CUPS.

```
> sudo lpinfo -m
lpinfo: Internal Server Error
```

Here is my [`/etc/cups/cupsd.conf`](http://pastebin.com/jwwTma33). I’m not even sure where to start. I tried commenting out suspicious lines, but to no success. How can I fix this?

I run CUPS `1.7.2-1` on debian wheezy/sid.

Comment: You should check the cups `error_log` file for more information. I don't have a Debian system, but on RHEL this is located at `/var/log/cups/error_log`

Answer (score 1):

This error can occur when `cups` is not started by `root`.

`sesu` to `root` will not work; it must be the actual `root` account. You can either login as `root` and do `service cups restart`, or you can make sure `cups` is on in `chkconfig` (`chkconfig cups on`), and then reboot.